# Raspberry PI 3 ARMEL support

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, arm

I am working with a vendor that provides drivers that aren't compatible with PI3's ARMHF architecture. Unfortunately this vendor doesn't plan on releasing compatible drivers anytime soon.

Excuse my inexperience, but is it possible to compile the current Raspbian OS to 'downgrade' from hard to soft float support? If not we will need to find a stable distro with armel support for the PI 3 or another solution (cross-compiling?).

Comment: You should include more information about what exactly these vendor drivers are, because if they are pre-compiled kernel objects you are looking at a potentially very difficult situation.

Comment: I'm working with the UareU SDK from Crossmatch [link](http://www.crossmatch.com/uareu-sdk-for-windows). It includes source for a USB driver, which I'm able to compile fine. The libraries included do not support ARMHF and the provided code samples aren't able to resolve some dynamic libraries at runtime due to ARMHF/ARMEL ABI mismatch. Is there an easier solution than 'downgrading' Raspbian? Perhaps I can compile the provided samples as ARMEL, recompile the driver as ARMEL and then I should be able to use the provided ARMEL libraries?

Comment: Debian has an armel port, you could investigate that and use the Rpi kernel.

Comment: We're really hoping we can stick with the official release of the Raspbian OS if possible. Excuse my inexperience, but I've been reading up on cross compilation - could that be a solution as well?

Comment: AFAIK Rapbian OS is just debian with a custom kernel and `/lib/modules`

Comment: If you have an armel cross-compiler and you can do a *static* build, you could try that.  No promises from me. @DmitryGrigoryev No, it is not the same as either Debian armel or armhf.  They made the confusing choice of referring to the packages as `armhf` -- which I guess is accurate enough, but Debian armhf is ARMv7, Raspbian is a form of ARMv6.  Debian's armel is v. 4 or 5+, software floats.

Comment: Ok, I'm installing Ubuntu now. Will be trying a static build using the cross compiler tools.